# Vuejs, отложенная отправка Axios запроса

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Имеется несколько вещей, которые требуют подобного решения, но разберу на примере меню одного из сайтов.

Есть меню (компонент), которое выводиться с помощью Vue. Цикл разбирает объект, который приходит в виде json-массива с PHP сервера, цикл берет название, ссылку и иконку объекта, после чего вставляет в HTML. Сам объект (массив) берется из API запроса на PHP сервер, сервер возвращает данные вида:

```json
{
name: "Главная страница",
icon: "fal fa-pump-soap",
link: "/"
},
{
name: "О нас",
icon: "fal fa-pump-soap",
link: "/about"
}
```

Теперь к сути проблемы, Axios запрос у меня находиться в mounted() {}, то есть запрос происходит при загрузке страницы.

Что конкретно мне нужно? На http://yandex.market/ имеется главное меню, нажав на кнопку "категории" у поиска открывается меню. Там так же отправляется API запрос с данными меню, ссылками, текстом и прочим. Но сам API запрос отправляется лишь после того, как пользователь открыл само меню. Как можно реализовать аналогичное на Vue? В голову лишь приходит событие по клику на кнопку "меню", что совершенно не верно.

Comment: Повесить прогрузку на `@mouseover` не?

Comment: @TotalPusher большое спасибо. (:

Answer (score 0):

Вы правильно думаете, запустить метод `.get` на `@click` когда по меню кликаете